# Getting the Information about folder of alfresco using java application

Tags: java, alfresco-share

I have  a my web appliacation which run on one server and alfresco application on another server.Now we are opening the alfresco share page using single-sign on.I want that if user click on particular folder then the information about that folder should be avilble to my web application.Is it possible to do so?
Yes then how?
and No then Why?

Please if any body have any idea then reply as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can get the information about current folder.
All you need to do is get the current folder id and call the webscript which will return you the folder details based on the noderef provided by you.
You can either use CMIS services to get the details.
Alfresco share also use the webscript call to get the details of content.